# HAProxy, why would a replaced HTTP header have a number at the end?

Tags: http, haproxy, http-headers, x-forwarded-for

Can someone explain what the "X-Forwarded-Proto2" header is in this HAProxy frontend stanza?:

```
frontend main *:443
  ...
  reqirep ^(X-Forwarded-Proto:)(.*) X-Forwarded-Proto2:\2
  ...
```

I understand that HAProxy is injecting a HTTP header.  But why is there a 2 at the end of the new string?  I'm referring to the number "2" at the end of the header, not the regex backreference.

Comment: Where did you see this?  It looks as if somebody wanted to rename the header `X-Forwarded-Proto:` to `X-Forwarded-Proto2:` for... whatever reason.  That's what this would do.

Comment: On a server that acts as a proxy to a java application.  I wasn't sure what to make of it at first, but I think it has something to do with the fact that we have multiple levels of proxying taking place.

Comment: Possibly added by someone who didn't understand how `X-Forwarded-For:` is supposed to work -- each intermediate proxy appends the incoming address on the end, so you read right-to-left, removing addresses of machines you trust, stopping at the first address (from the right) that's not one of yours.  Maybe you have a component that chokes on longish but valid values.  (I ran into a system once that blew up of the XFF was > 45 bytes.  Naïve coding at its finest, since 3 IP addresses only worked if not all the octets were 3 digits each. Yuck.)  But there's no standard reason for this config.